# How to save 10^19 in Julia without an overflow

Tags: julia

I am trying to save the number 10^19 in a variable in Julia.

I know it is overflowing, but I figured that doing something like `BigInt(10^19)` or `Int128(10^19)` would solve the problem but it doesn't.

Any thoughts?

[See overflow behavior for Julia](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/integers-and-floating-point-numbers/#Overflow-behavior-1)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Julia does Int64 arithmetic by default, so the 10^19 overflows as the default Int64 before the surrounding parentheses casting to a bigger type are encountered.  Try

```
Int128(10)^20 == BigInt(10)^20 == big"10"^20
```

Comment: Just as a side comment: Julia could be clever enough to detect what range constants like 10^19 fit in and use the smallest type large enough to fit the constant, or some other heuristics that doesn't fail.

Comment: Indeed, my guess would be this results in the performance hit so they push it downstream to the user.

Comment: It's less that, and more that conceptually it is in some ways cleaner to have simple rules like if it looks like an int, it's an int